# Only values of one form of many get send

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post

I am creating a search interface, letting the user chose a row from a table with anything between 1 - 500 rows and find entries similar to the one selected.

Right now, I have a form of checkboxes for each row and get the values directly in php.

part of index.php

```
<table>
<tr><!-- several tds -->
    <td><form action="pfile.php" name="findsimilar1" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="red">
        <!-- several more checkboxes with attributes -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="darkness" value="8">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_b">
   </form></td></tr>
<tr><!-- several tds-->
    <td><form action="pfile.php" name="findsimilar2" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="blue">
        <!-- several more checkboxes with attributes -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="darkness" value="2">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_b">
    </form></td></tr>
<tr><!-- several tds-->
    <td><form action="pfile.php" name="findsimilar3" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="green">
        <!-- several more checkboxes with attributes -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="darkness" value="5">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_b">
    </form></td></tr></table>
```

part of pfile.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_b'])){
    if(isset($_POST['color'])){
        $c = $_POST['color'];
    }
if(isset($_POST['darkness'])){
        $d = $_POST['darkness'];
    }
}
```

But only the values of the first/last entry get send. I already - after reading answers to similar questions - changed the name of the forms to be unique by appending the rownumber to the name, but this does not change the behaviour.

The user may click all, one or several of the checkboxes.

I want only the values of the form whose button was clicked to be send.
php-version: 5.3.3
Browser: Firefox ESR 38.6.0

Any pointers into the right direction or what I might have missed?

Is Jquery maybe the better way to go?

---

Edits:

- added 'method="post"'
- clarified that many checkboxes and none obligatory

Comment: @JonStirling is right, and I think that you have to tell us, if you need just one **color** and one **darkness** in your php or multiple values.

Comment: Didn't he say "I want only the values of the form whose button was clicked to be send"? So, only the form of 1 TR should be sent: 2 items "color" and "darkness".

Comment: @hherger You are right. Obviously didn't pay enough attention. Comment removed.

Comment: So... he should use a single form with radio for colors and disabled checkbox for darkness, which will be enabled only if the proper color is selected.

Comment: But how do you send data to server? If just submiting the form by clicking button, without any javascript involved, then what you said shouldn't happen. In fact, you are sending GET request, not POST but that's in contardiction with what you said, so really hard to get what is your issue...

Comment: @Vixed I didnt anticipate this interpretation, so I will clarify: no, there are many checkboxes to select from, and the user may check whatever he wants. And I am using POST, edited above.

Answer (score 0):

Either add **method="POST"**
(your table a bit beautified)

```
<table>
<tr><th style="text-align:left">color</th><th>darkness</th><th> </th></tr>
<tr><!-- several tds -->
    <form action="pfile.php" name="findsimilar1" method="POST">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="color" value="red">red</input></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="darkness" value="8">active</input></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit_b" /></td>
   </form>
</tr>
<tr><!-- several tds-->
    <form action="pfile.php" name="findsimilar2">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="color" value="blue">blue</input></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="darkness" value="2">active</input></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit_b" /></td>
    </form>
</tr>
<tr><!-- several tds-->
    <form action="pfile.php" name="findsimilar3">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="color" value="green">green</input></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="darkness" value="5">active</input></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit_b" /></td>
    </form>
</tr>
</table>
```

...or change $_POST to **$_REQUEST** (which covers both GET and POST methods)
Btw: always initialize variables and do not let them "unset" if you later will access them.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit_b'])){
    $color    = isset($_REQUEST['color'])    ? $_REQUEST['color']    : false;
    $darkness = isset($_REQUEST['darkness']) ? $_REQUEST['darkness'] : false;
    if ($color !== false) && ($darkness !== false) {
        // Do anything...
    }
} else {
    // Nothing to do...
}
```

Comment: I use post, I forgot to add it as a table attribute, is now edited.

Comment: Oh, _method="POST"_ is not a table attribute but a **FORM** attribute. My php code accepts both GET and POST, since I use the $_REQUEST variables not $_GET or $_POST! In the html code **only one** form sends POST variables now!

Comment: I am sloppy today - of course it's a form attribute and all forms have it, updating it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

**Using jQuery** you can also test it on **[this new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/dbpq7dyu/)**

> HTML and JS

```
<form action="pfile.php" method="post" id="findsimilar">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ckColor" value="red">
            <input type="checkbox" name="ckDarkness" value="8">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ckColor" value="blue">
            <input type="checkbox" name="ckDarkness" value="2">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ckColor" value="green">
            <input type="checkbox" name="ckDarkness" value="5">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="color" />
    <input type="hidden" name="darkness" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_b">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var chkDarkness= $('#findsimilar input[name="ckDarkness"]');
var chkColors=$('#findsimilar input[name="ckColor"]');
var getGolor=$('input[name="color"]');
var getDarkness=$('input[name="darkness"]');

chkColors.on('click',function(){
    var el=$(this);
    var elDark=el.parent().find('input[name="ckDarkness"]');
    chkDarkness.not(elDark).prop('checked',false);
    if (el.is(':checked')){
        chkColors.not(el).prop('checked',false);
        getGolor.val(el.val());
        if (!elDark.is(':checked'))
           getDarkness.val('');
    } else {
       getGolor.val('');
       if (!elDark.is(':checked'))
           getDarkness.val('');

    }
});

chkDarkness.on('click',function(){
    var el=$(this);
    var elCol=el.parent().find('input[name="ckColor"]');
    getDarkness.val('');
    chkDarkness.not(el).prop('checked',false);
    chkColors.not(elCol).prop('checked',false);
    if (el.is(':checked'))
       getDarkness.val(el.val());
       if (!elCol.is(':checked'))
           getGolor.val('');

})
</script>
```

> PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_b'])){
    if(isset($_POST['color']))
        $c = $_POST['color'];

    if(isset($_POST['darkness']))
        $d = $_POST['darkness']
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that your solution is working ok. Which checkbox "color" and "darkness" value will be transmitted? And, btw., the OA said "I want only the values of the form whose button was clicked to be sent".

Comment: What do you mean by "obligatory"? It's a checkbox - either checked or not.

Comment: I know but one at least it's required or not?

Comment: Nothing of the checkboxes should be obligatory, as long as you check at least one checkbox. The actual number of checkboxes is not fixed, right now there are 8, and the user can select any.

Comment: but I still have to check the color first - what if i only want to find entries that have the same 'darkness'-value?

Comment: Sorry a mistake with version four this works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/o06df9rv/5/

Comment: @PaeHu did you tested?

Comment: will get to it this week.

Comment: It' s still the values of only the first form that get sent. I think the error is somewhere else though.